# How to use Custom Font with Youtube Player?

Tags: java, android, youtube-data-api, custom-font

I have successfully integrated YouTube Player in my app but I am not able to use a custom font to other UI elements. On other Activities, the font is working.

```
public class PlayerActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements CustomAdapter.Listner {

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_player);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where you want to use that fonts?

Comment: Hi Sagar Gujarati, I want to use font on other UI element on my XML activity like TextViews.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. 
By using `YoutubePlayerSupportFragment` instead of `YoutubePlayerView` I can simply use `AppCompatActivity` and hence use Custom fonts in XML.